# JaxRS set resource class with constructor

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a `jaxrs` server and I want to set a resource class. The problem is that my class has a constructor in which I inject another dependency of another object.

```
      final JAXRSServerFactoryBean serverFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
      serverFactory.setResourceClasses( MessageService.class);
      serverFactory.setResourceProvider( MessageService.class,
            new SingletonResourceProvider( new MessageService() ) );
      serverFactory.setAddress( "http://localhost:8080/service/" );

      serverFactory.setProvider( JacksonJsonProvider.class );
      serverFactory.create();
```

My `MessageService` class:

```
public class MessageService
{

   private final MessageProvider mp;


   public MessageService( final MessageProvider messageProvider )
   {
      this.mp = messageProvider;
   }
}
```

I get the error : `resource class MessageService has no valid constructor`

Can you help me solve this?